# How can I start my Slideshow automaically on page load

Tags: jquery, slider, onload

I've built a small slideshow in jQuery. It's very simple. How can I start the slider automatically on page load? The slider should run all the time. Only If a user clicks my thumbnails, the slider jump direct to that slide.

```
var totalWidth = 0;
var positions = new Array();

$('.slides .slide').each(function (i) {
    positions[i] = totalWidth;
    totalWidth += $(this).width();
});

$('.slides').width(totalWidth);

$('.slideMenu ul li a').click(function (e) {
    var pos = $(this).parent().prevAll('.menuItem').length;
    $('.slides').stop().animate({
        marginLeft: -positions[pos] + 'px'
    }, 450);

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

[Here is my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/9w925/1/)

Comment: Please include your code within the question. A jsfiddle is great, but if the site goes down your question would be unanswerable.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
function goNextSlide() {
    // Do animate stuff here
    setTimeout(goNextSlide(), 60);
}

$( document ).ready(function() {
    goNextSlide();
});
```

or a quick hack for you that might work:

```
function goNextSlide(slide) {
    $(".slideMenu ul li a:nth-child("+slide+")").click();
    slide++;
    if(slide>3) {
         slide = 0;   
    }
    setTimeout(goNextSlide(slide), 600);
}

$( document ).ready(function() {
    goNextSlide(1);
});
```

Comment: sorry, I try to check the code .. but I've still have problems with that ... hehehe. I try my best -...